# convert single quotes string to double

Tags: ruby

I have problems working with .gsub ir .delete functions on received results from the database. I guess these results comes in single quotes, so I'm getting different results:

```
<%= "Remove \n".delete("\n") %>
result: "Remove" 
<%= 'Remove \n'.delete("\n") %>
result: "Remove \"
```

So, how to convert single quoted strings to duoble quoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with single/double quoted strings. Your database stores the backslash literally as `\` instead of storing a new line character.

Consider the following:

```
irb(main):016:0> puts "Result \n"
Result
=> nil
irb(main):017:0> puts 'Result \n'
Result \n
=> nil
```

Try quoting the backslash in your replacement string:

```
'Remove \n'.delete("\\\\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use .tr to perform this replacement operation

```
.tr("'",'"')
```

Comment: 'Remove \n'.tr("'",'"').delete("\n") still doesn't work :(

Comment: @Gediminas 'Remove \n'.tr("'",'"') procudes "Remove \\n". I think we need some further task to convert slash+alphanumeric literal into the escaped token.